# How to reset a default sorting after datagrid bindings refreshed

Tags: wpf, sorting, datagrid

One datagrid, and all the columns have sort config, if click header, one specified sorting triggered, and data refreshed on purpose。 But when refresh the whole datagrid data, it seems datagrid remember the last sorting condition, so my question is how to reset to default sorting if someone refresh whole datagrid?

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong but since you are using sorting in datagrid I assume that datagrid is bound to `ICollectionView`. If you want to reset sorting on refreshing the grid, simply clear the `ICollectionView.SortDescriptions` or reset it to default values.

If this is not the case, consider using a ICollectionView as a source for your datagrid. It provides features such as sorting, filtering and grouping out of the box and easy to implement and customize.

You can find some useful resources here:

- [MSDN: ICollectionView Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [MSDN: How to: Group, Sort, and Filter Data in the DataGrid Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407126(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Dr.WPF: ItemsControl: 'C' is for Collection](http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/11/05/itemscontrol-c-is-for-collection/)
- [Dr.WPF: ItemsControl: 'E' is for Editable Collection](http://drwpf.com/blog/2008/10/20/itemscontrol-e-is-for-editable-collection/)

Comment: Thanks, let me check resources what you provided first ~